# datepicker won't change date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to change the date format for my datepicker, but it doesn't want to change, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dateselect').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#dateform').submit(); // 
    }});
});
```

even so, the format on the front end is still mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [jQuery UI Datepicker widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), the way to change the date format is

```
dateFormat
```

and not

```
format
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: Still not working, I've been trying that even before.. pretty strange..

Comment: Sorry, was the cache, cleared everything again and it works, thank you!

Comment: Okay, just made a jsfiddle showing it works: https://jsfiddle.net/bcqL71v3/ - If my answer helped you please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers